# My servo motor isnt moving when ir sensor senses something

Tags: python, arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno

I am trying to get the servo motor to turn 180 degrees and then back to 0 degrees when the IR sensor senses something
[Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tzCg.jpg)

```py
import time
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util

board = Arduino('COM5')

iterator = util.Iterator(board)
iterator.start()

motor = board.get_pin('d:6:s')

sensorPinNo = 2

sensorPin = board.get_pin('d:' + str(sensorPinNo) + ':i')

print("Nothing is being sensed ")

rlt = sensorPin.read()
while True:
    if rlt:
        print("Sensor has detected something")

        def setServoAngle(angle):
            print("Wiping In Progress")
            for i in range(0, 180):
                setServoAngle(i)
                motor.write(angle)
            for i in range(180, 1, -1):
                setServoAngle(i)
                motor.write(angle)

        print("Program Exit")
        board.exit()
```

I have:
Arduino uno,
servo motor,
IR sensor,
Buzzer,
LED,
Resistors,
Breadboard,
Jumper wires

Comment: Never used this library, but aren't you supposed to call the read function from within the loop ? My guess is that because you only call it once the value never gets updated

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here, not all of which I can fix, but:

```py
import time
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util

board = Arduino('COM5')

iterator = util.Iterator(board)
iterator.start()

motor = board.get_pin('d:6:s')

sensorPinNo = 2

sensorPin = board.get_pin('d:' + str(sensorPinNo) + ':i')

print("Nothing is being sensed ")

while True:
    rlt = sensorPin.read()
    if rlt:
        print("Sensor has detected something")

        print("Wiping In Progress")
        for i in range(0, 180):
            motor.write(i)
        for i in range(180, 1, -1):
            motor.write(i)

print("Program Exit")
board.exit()
```

Note that your function wasn't called and in the end seemed redundant.

Also note that this program does not exit. I don't know what condition is needed to exit.

Comment: quamrana the exit condition i have yet to go there but it should be a input() code where the user types in any alphabet to exit, but could u please help me solve some of the errors

Comment: main issue right now is the sensor is working like when i put my finger in front of it that small led lights up but in the code where "Sensor has detected something" doesnt come out

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I don't have your hardware to test my code on.

Comment: its alright! but is there anything u can figure out from the code or from the picture of my circuit i attached ?

Comment: I think that you need to do the debugging. Just `print(rlt)` inside the loop.

Comment: is there an issue with the if rlt: ? cause when i put print(rlt) after while true: its correct as it constantly prints out none but when the ir sensor sense something it doesnt run thru the if rlt: code

Comment: One step at a time. What does it print out? Is it only `None`, or something else when it senses something?

Comment: yup its just none. when it senses something nothing happens

Comment: So the `if` is irrelevant at this stage until you can get the sensor working. How did you know to write the code you have to address the sensor?

Comment: sorry i dont quite understand what u mean

Comment: I mean, what is: `board.get_pin(...)`? How do you know that is correct?

Comment: hmm the only i plugged into the arduino uno board for the sensor is 2